# How to access methods inside custom pivot model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm using Laravel 8, and having many-to-many relationship using custom pivot model as explained [here in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-custom-intermediate-table-models). However, I don't know how can I access the methods that I have created inside the custom pivot model.

Let's say, using the example provided in the doc, I created some methods inside the `RoleUser` model. My question is: how can I access those methods from `Role` model, from something like `Role::find(1)->users()` ? Is it possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as accessing any attribute from pivot.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns

```
use App\Models\User;
 
$user = User::find(1);
 
foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    echo $role->pivot->methodInPivot();
}
```

Comment: I posted another question following this matter here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73091687/many-to-many-relationship-but-the-pivot-table-also-having-its-own-many-to-many-r. Hope you could see it and give answers if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**In Role** model define the relationship.

```
class Role extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

}
```

> ***Important:*** piot table must be singular format and sorted by alphabetic order. ex `role_user`.

> If you defied as `roles_user`, you need a custom mapping in the user relationship in the role model.

**In Controller**

```
public function funcName()
{
    # You can use all the Eloquent methods like where, get, first etc...
    $roles = Role::with('users')->get(); 
    return view('view_name', compact('roles'));
}
```

**In View**

```
foreach($roles as $role)
{
    Role name - {{$role->name}}

    foreach($role->users as $user)
    {
        user name - {{$user->name}}
    }
}
```

> To access **any additional field inside the pivot table**, you can use the `->pivot` prefix. Ex `$user->pivot->created_at`

Answer (score 0):

1. Your intermediate table model needs to extend `Pivot`, not `Model` class.
2. You should specify pivot class by calling
   `->withPivot('additional_field')->using(MyPivotModel::class)` in relation method.