# Many-to-many relationship but the pivot table also having its own many-to-many relationship. How can I implement eager load in it?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

How can I implement eager load in a many-to-many relationship that exists in a pivot table? I've succeed in retrieving it by lazy loading, but I'm trying to find the eager load way (I'm using L8).

I have 5 tables which related to one another as shown below (simplified):

[image: table structure]

From the 5 tables above, I've created 4 models:

- `Class`
- `Period`
- `ClassPeriod`, as a pivot model
- `Teacher`

`Class` has `belongsToMany()` relationship to `Period`, which `using()` the `ClassPeriod` pivot model. Common stuff. Eager loads related to these 3 models have been easily done. However, I'm confused on how can I eager load `Teacher` from `Class`.

To retrieve `Teacher` from `Class` by lazy loading as I mentioned, I've created the following:

- Create `teachers` method with `belongsToMany()` relationship in `ClassPeriod`
- Create `getTeachersAttribute` method which calls the `teachers` method above

Then the retrievement can be performed in 2 ways:

- Way number 1 is using the `pivot` attribute, something like:

  ```php
  $classes = Class::with(['periods'])->get();
  foreach($classes as $class) {
      echo $class->pivot->teachers;
  }
  ```
- Way number 2 is by utilizing the `appends` property in the model. So inside `ClassPeriod`, I added:

  ```php
  protected $appends = [ 'teachers' ];
  ```

  thus `Class::with(['periods'])` will have `teachers` appended to the pivot automatically

So, back to the question, how can I achieve the above in eager loads? Is it possible? Your input is much appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call nested relationships with dot `.` in your with() method.

So your query will be:

> Class::with('periods')->with('class_period.teachers');

And create the relationship in **Class** :

> public function class_period(){return $this->hasMany(ClassPeriod::class,'class_id');}

And in your **ClassPeriod** class the relationship:

> public function teachers(){return $this->belongsToMany(Teachers::class)->using(ClassPeriodTeacher::class);}

You can add wheres and [whereRelation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#inline-relationship-existence-queries) to add more logic to your query.

Comment: I actually thought of something like that, but not sure on how to execute it. What I had in mind is to define `periods.teachers` or maybe `periods.classPeriodTeacher` using `hasManyTrough()` relationship, but I'm not sure if it'll works correctly because `class_period_teacher` takes the id of `class_period` (which has the combination of `classes` id and `periods` id), not just the id of `periods`. What do you think?

Comment: I update my answer please see if this help you and accept it if works.

Comment: Sorry, but you're mistaken. `teachers` method is defined inside the `ClassPeriod` pivot model, not in `Class`.

Comment: Oh sorry I will update again my answer

Comment: I get a bit confused at first, but [this article](https://p.softonsofa.com/laravel-custom-pivot-model-in-eloquent/) helps me in understanding that `belongsToMany()` is actually the combination of `hasMany()` and `belongsTo()`. Works like charm. Thank you so much for your help!